# Beautifulsoup - How to open images and download them

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to grab the full size product images from [here](http://icecat.biz/p/toshiba/pscbxe-01t00een/satellite-pro-notebooks-4051528049077-Satellite+Pro+C8501GR-17732197.html)

My thinking was:

- Follow the image link
- Download the picture
- Go back
- Repeat for n+1 pictures

I know how to open the image thumbnails but not how to get the full size images. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 22):

This will get you all URL of the images:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://icecat.biz/p/toshiba/pscbxe-01t00een/satellite-pro-notebooks-4051528049077-Satellite+Pro+C8501GR-17732197.html"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

imgs = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"thumb-pic"})
for img in imgs:
        print img.a['href'].split("imgurl=")[1]
```

Output:

```
http://www.toshiba.fr/contents/fr_FR/SERIES_DESCRIPTION/images/g1_satellite-pro-c850.jpg
http://www.toshiba.fr/contents/fr_FR/SERIES_DESCRIPTION/images/g4_satellite-pro-c850.jpg
http://www.toshiba.fr/contents/fr_FR/SERIES_DESCRIPTION/images/g2_satellite-pro-c850.jpg
http://www.toshiba.fr/contents/fr_FR/SERIES_DESCRIPTION/images/g5_satellite-pro-c850.jpg
http://www.toshiba.fr/contents/fr_FR/SERIES_DESCRIPTION/images/g3_satellite-pro-c850.jpg
```

And this code is for downloading and saving those images:

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://icecat.biz/p/toshiba/pscbxe-01t00een/satellite-pro-notebooks-4051528049077-Satellite+Pro+C8501GR-17732197.html"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

imgs = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"thumb-pic"})
for img in imgs:
        imgUrl = img.a['href'].split("imgurl=")[1]
        urllib.urlretrieve(imgUrl, os.path.basename(imgUrl))
```

Comment: Some of other items on this site don't have full resolution images (the images were moved or deleted). So only option for that is to download thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
```

In that section i just hit medium website and getting all trending top links

```
URL = "https://medium.com/"
page = requests.get(URL)
trending_on_mediums = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
trending_links = soup.find('div', class_='al ah')
links = trending_links.find_all('div', class_='ew n bc ex ey ez fa fb fc fd fe ff fg fh fi fj fk fl fm')
for i in links:
    for j in i:
        link = j.contents[0].find_all('a', class_='bd be bf bg bh bi bj bk bl bm bn bo bp bq br')[1]['href']
        if 'https://' not in link:
            link = 'https://medium.com' + link
        trending_on_mediums.append(link)
```

Now we hit one by one link and get all text data and images

```
for url in trending_on_mediums:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    name = soup.title.text
    image_url = soup.find('source').get('srcset').split(',')[0][:-5]
    file_name = ''.join(name.split('|')[1]).replace("by", "")
    f = open(f"{file_name}.text", "a")
    f.write(soup.text)
    f.close()
    if image_url:
        image_bytes = requests.get(image_url)
        image_io = BytesIO(image_bytes.content)

        image = Image.open(image_io)
        image = image.convert("RGB")
        image.save(f"{file_name}.jpg", format="JPEG")
```

I m using Pillow image for manipulating images, you can use whatever you want. You can install pillow library from following command.

```
pip install Pillow
```

documentation link: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/