# Python script to download all images and captions from a flickr url

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to write a python script using urllib2 to download all the images with captions from [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/flickr/galleries/72157652879582045/)

```
from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall
from Tkinter import *
import urllib, cStringIO
import random 

photo_window=Tk()
photo_window.title('Photo Browser')
import base64
url = "https://www.flickr.com/photos/flickr/galleries/72157652879582045/"
regex = '<img src="([^"]+)".*>'
photofile=urllib.urlopen(url)
raw_data=photofile.read()
pattern = re.compile(regex)
download=re.findall(pattern,raw_data)
t=0
for x in download:
    urllib.urlretrieve(x, "local-filename-%d.gif" %t )
    t+=1
```

This allows me to download all the images, but I am still struggling to only get the full images (not the thumbnails) and to get the captions as well

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @konart I am having a lot of difficulty associating the images with the captions and with downloading them at all

Comment: please show how far you've gone with coding...

Comment: Sorry I am very new to python. See the edited post above

Comment: @diffracteD here is my code. I am still struggling to get the captions as well

Comment: What is the error or problem you're having?

Comment: @Camron_Godbout I am struggling to only get the full sized images(Not the thumbnails or the user profile pictures) and also get the caption/title for each picture in the gallery

Comment: I would reccomend parsing the HTML using beautiful soup or lxml and grabbing the pictures from inside <div class="gallery-photos"> then get the title as the caption

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497840/beautifulsoup-how-to-open-images-and-download-them

Comment: Unfortuanatly I am not allowed to use either of those libraries

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I can't comment, I would have but ...

For the "big size" pictures, when you got a bloc like this one :

```
<img class="pc_img" width="640" border="0" height="426" data-thumbdata="" alt="Falls in the bush - Zambia" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2035/2399025352_d96e82fbe1_z.jpg">
```

the image src (on Flickr) as a little attribute at the end `(_z)` if you change it to, let's say `_b` you'll have a bigger sized picture. This is all explained [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)

So what you can do is parse the image source's adress and replace _z with _o for the original size !

Comment: Also, you should take a look at the [http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi] FlickrAPI for Python, I've used the Flickr API in Javascript, and it's very easy to handle, and can totally achieve what you're trying to do !