# How to Send post response as image from python requests

Tags: python, web, python-requests

i am trying to get my image hosted online and for that i am using python

```
import requests 
url = 'http://imgup.net/'
data = {'image[image][]':'http://www.webhost-resources.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/dedicated-hosting-server.jpg'}
r = requests.post(url, files=data)
```

i am not able to get the response url of the hosted image from the response . 
Please help !

Comment: r.text gives me the same html page which doesn't contain the post response from server side !

Comment: If you trying donwload an image use [beautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497840/beautifulsoup-how-to-open-images-and-download-them)

Comment: The requests docs say you have to give a dictionary with values being a file-like object, not a URL.

Comment: @RahulRao I made it work, wait a minute while I compile my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `files` parameter of `requests.post` needs a:

> Dictionary of `'name': file-like-objects` (or `{'name': ('filename', fileobj)}`) for multipart encoding upload.

2. There's more data you'll need to send than just the file, most importantly the "authenticity token". If you look at the source code of the page, it'll show you all other parameters as `<input type="hidden">` tags.
3. The upload URL is http://imgup.net/upload, as you can see from the `action` attribute of `<form>`.

---

So what you need to do is:

1. Download the image you want to upload (I'll call it `dhs.jpg`).
2. Do a GET request of the main page, extracting the `authenticity_token`.
3. Once you have that, send the request with `files=` and `data=`:

‌

```
url = "http://imgup.net/upload"
data = {'utf8': '&#x2713;', 'authenticity_token': '<put your scraped token here>', '_method': 'put'}
f = open("dhs.jpg", "rb")  # open in binary mode
files = {'image[image][]': f}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
f.close()
print(r.json()["image_link"]
```

---

*Final note: While I couldn't find any rule against this behaviour in their T&C, the presence of an authenticity token makes it seem likely that imgup doesn't really want you to do this automatically*.

Comment: could you please work it out if my question is clear ?

Comment: i think there is no authenticity token . please correct me if it's illegal becuase the code is working without any authentication Thanks bro !